# Need help to create a formula in google spreadsheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I Would like to create a formula to show in a cell the winning/loosing streak of a range if the number is positive or negative, and I would like to add the sum of the total value of the streak in a separate cell.

for example I have a basic table with

A1:A100 I have different number positive or negative and in B1 I want to show the longest positive streak of the range, let's say is from A25 to A45 so the value should be 10, and in B2 I want to show the total value of the sum of A25 to A45.
In C1 and C2 the same but for negative

EDIT:
I would like also To show the highest sum of negative/positive of any streak in the range not especially the longest

I hope is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

D1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(, IF(A:A>0, 1, 0)), 0))))
```

D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(, IF(A:A<0, 1, 0)), 0))))
```

D3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SPLIT(INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE({LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(, 
 IF(A:A>0, 1, "♥")), "♥")); SPLIT(JOIN(, 
 IF(A:A>0, A:A&"♦", "♥")), "♥")}), 1, 0), 1, 2), "♦")))
```

D4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SPLIT(INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE({LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(, 
 IF(A:A<0, 1, "♥")), "♥")); SPLIT(JOIN(, 
 IF(A:A<0, A:A&"♦", "♥")), "♥")}), 1, 0), 1, 2), "♦")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help but the positive formula are not working, they give me wrong number  =ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(, IF(D:D>0, 1, 0)), 0)))) and =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SPLIT(INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE({LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(, 
 IF(D:D>0, 1, "♥")), "♥")); SPLIT(JOIN(, 
 IF(D:D>0, D:D&"♦", "♥")), "♥")}), 1, 0), 1, 2), "♦")))  my table start at row 22 actualy

Comment: my table start from D22 up to any i put D360 but i can go longer, every cell in the column is =IF(OR(F50<>""),(SUM(F50-C50)/C50*100),"") from D22 to any and the i already have entrie up to D51 but after there is still =IF(OR(F50<>""),(SUM(F50-C50)/C50*100),"") but is empty at the moment

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: provided formulas in answer are all correct. your issue is the formula you use in D30:D. instead of `=IF(OR(F30<>""),(SUM(F30-C30)/C30*100),"")` you need to use `=IF(OR(F30<>""),(SUM(F30-C30)/C30*100),)` note that using `""` it doesn't mean you output empty cell. what you are actually outputing is "cell full of nothing"

Comment: thx very much is working :-) I have few other think to sort out if you don't mind to ask

Comment: OK I sorted out my other formula but I still one problem to solve, how to make your formula =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SPLIT(INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE({LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(, 
 IF(A:A>0, 1, "♥")), "♥")); SPLIT(JOIN(, 
 IF(A:A>0, A:A&"♦", "♥")), "♥")}), 1, 0), 1, 2), "♦"))) to get the Highest sum even if the streak is not the longest

Comment: for that you may use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdnvA.png

Comment: change `INDIRECT("E25:E...` to be `INDIRECT("E1:E...` - that should fix the array matrix error

Comment: oh ok thx is working ! Thank you very much :-) but when I the sign in the formula to have it for negative number I'll get the smallest number of the range,  I don't know what to change to get negative highest value, is it a 1 in 2 ? =ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(MMULT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(, IF(E25:E<0, E25:E&"♦","♥")), "♥")), "♦")*1,ROW(INDIRECT("E1:E"& MAX(LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(, IF(E25:E<0, 1, 0)), 0)))))^0)))

Comment: change `MAX(MMULT(` to be  `MIN(MMULT(` - that should fix the highest negative

Comment: I am trying to do one more thing if you don't mind i am trying to make a formula to be able to selection a specific range within the range in a drop down cell for example I would like to be able to see if I selection 1 day, week or 1 month the sum of that range selection and that for all the column in a sub total kind of way